# How to exclude specific county from Entry Node by torrc file?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

Its known its possible to set specific countrys by adding lines like follow, to torrc file from Tor browser.

```
EntryNodes {??},{ug},{us},{fr} StrictNodes 1
```

```
ExitNodes {??},{ug},{us},{fr} StrictNodes 1
```

Its known its possible to exclude specific countrys by adding line like follow, to torrc file as entry, middle and exid node for Tor browser.

```
ExcludeNodes {??},{ug},{us},{fr} StrictNodes 1
```

Its known its possible to exclude specific countrys by adding line like follow, to torrc file as entry, middle and exid node for Tor browser.

```
ExcludeExitNodes {??},{ug},{us},{fr} StrictNodes 1
```

The two-character country code on samples above, according to ISO3166 can be used in either upper or lower case letters.

How to exclude specific country by adding some stuff on torrc file, only as Tor Entry node?

To setup a actual full country list minus the country which should be excluded, don't make much sense, because the count of country and the country list are not static and change a little bit from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a list of all country codes: https://b3rn3d.herokuapp.com/blog/2014/03/05/tor-country-codes

I created in advance:

{ac},{af},{ax},{al},{dz},{ad},{ao},{ai},{aq},{ag},{ar},{am},{aw},{au},{at},{az},{bs},{bh},{bd},{bb},{by},{be},{bz},{bj},{bm},{bt},{bo},{ba},{bw},{bv},{br},{io},{vg},{bn},{bg},{bf},{bi},{kh},{cm},{ca},{cv},{ky},{cf},{td},{cl},{cn},{cx},{cc},{co},{km},{cg},{cd},{ck},{cr},{ci},{hr},{cu},{cy},{cz},{dk},{dj},{dm},{do},{tp},{ec},{eg},{sv},{gq},{ee},{et},{fk},{fo},{fj},{fi},{fr},{fx},{gf},{pf},{tf},{ga},{gm},{ge},{de},{gh},{gi},{gr},{gl},{gd},{gp},{gu},{gt},{gn},{gw},{gy},{ht},{hm},{hn},{hk},{hu},{is},{in},{id},{ir},{iq},{ie},{im},{il},{it},{jm},{jp},{jo},{kz},{ke},{ki},{kp},{kr},{kw},{kg},{la},{lv},{lb},{ls},{lr},{ly},{li},{lt},{lu},{mo},{mk},{mg},{mw},{my},{mv},{ml},{mt},{mh},{mq},{mr},{mu},{yt},{mx},{fm},{md},{mc},{mn},{me},{ms},{ma},{mz},{mm},{na},{nr},{np},{an},{nl},{nc},{nz},{ni},{ne},{ng},{nu},{nf},{mp},{no},{om},{pk},{pw},{ps},{pa},{pg},{py},{pe},{ph},{pn},{pl},{pt},{pr},{qa},{re},{ro},{ru},{rw},{ws},{sm},{st},{sa},{uk},{sn},{rs},{sc},{sl},{sg},{sk},{si},{sb},{so},{as},{za},{gs},{su},{es},{lk},{sh},{kn},{lc},{pm},{vc},{sd},{sr},{sj},{sz},{se},{ch},{sy},{tw},{tj},{tz},{th},{tg},{tk},{to},{tt},{tn},{tr},{tm},{tc},{tv},{ug},{ua},{ae},{gb},{uk},{us},{um},{uy},{uz},{vu},{va},{ve},{vn},{vi},{wf},{eh},{ye},{zm},{zw}

What you should do is excluding the country code you wish from the list and add the block to torrc together with EntryNodes and set StrictNodes to 1.

The country codes can be written in small letters and in capitals. Booth are valid in this case.

Comment: Did you understand my answer? Pick up a list of all countries, exclude the country(ies) you want and add to EntryNodes and add also StrictNodes 1. I know that is not the way you expected to do what you want, but it's the only way.

Comment: To be able to define only the accepted country's will be perfect, but that's looks that's possible not able in this case.